# Python Single Decimal

Tags: python, decimal

When I enter this code the answer ends with 2 characters behind the decimal. How do I make this only have 1 number behind it?

```
tempature=float(input("Enter the temp(F):"))
formant_tempature = f"{tempature:2f}"
print(round(((int(tempature)-32)*5/9)+273.15,2))
```

Comment: Might be a dumb question but I'm new to python and this would be a big help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you used round function you have specified that you want two decimal places. Just replace 2 with a number 1.

```
print(round(((int(tempature)-32)*5/9)+273.15,1))
```

Comment: Just what I needed. Thank you Aleksa.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the string formatting operator for that ( formant_tempature = f"{tempature:2f}" )

> What about **formant_tempature = f"{tempature:1f}"**

Like if you want it to display 5 decimals, just change it to f"{tempature:5f}"

And so on.

And for the round method, change 2 to 1.

Comment: For some reason this is not the case. I can always go past 1. For example if I put a 5 in its place it would have 5 characters after the decimal but it never seems to work for just 1. I appreciate the help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you'd do any math just to present this rounded, when you can simply use an f-string to specify outputting the temperature with a single decimal place precision.

```
>>> temperature = 43.8934
>>> print(f"Temperature is {temperature:.1f} degrees")
Temperature is 43.9 degrees
>>> print(f"Temperature is {temperature * 1.8 + 32:.1f} degrees farenheit")
Temperature is 111.0 degrees farenheit
```

Comment: Next time I will use this. Thank you Chris.